Why am I getting $E(\text{SSE}) = (n-1)\sigma^2$ instead of $E(\text{SSE}) = (n-2)\sigma^2$?
I am attempting to derive the expected value of the Sum of Squares for Error (SSE) in a simple linear regression model. According to standard theory, the expected value should be:
$$
E(\text{SSE}) = (n-2)\sigma^2
$$
However, my derivation consistently yields:
$$
E(\text{SSE}) = (n-1)\sigma^2
$$
Here is my step-by-step derivation:

Starting with the decomposition:
$$
E(\text{SSE}) = E(\text{SST} - \text{SSR}) = E(\text{SST}) - E(\text{SSR})
$$

Deriving $E(\text{SST})$:
$$
E(\text{SST}) = E\left(\sum (y_i - \bar{y})^2\right)
$$

Expanding the formula:
$$
\sum (y_i - \bar{y})^2 = \sum \left((\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i) - (\beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar{x})\right)^2
$$

Simplifying further:
$$
\sum (y_i - \bar{y})^2 = \sum \left(\beta_1 (x_i - \bar{x}) + \epsilon_i\right)^2 = \sum \left(\beta_1^2 (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + \epsilon_i^2 + 2 \beta_1 \epsilon_i (x_i - \bar{x})\right)
$$

Taking the expectation:
$$
E(\text{SST}) = \sum \beta_1^2 (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + \sum E(\epsilon_i^2) + 2 \beta_1 \sum (x_i - \bar{x}) E(\epsilon_i)
$$
Since $E(\epsilon_i) = 0$, this reduces to:
$$
E(\text{SST}) = \beta_1^2 \sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + n \sigma^2
$$

Deriving $E(\text{SSR})$:
$$
E(\text{SSR}) = \beta_1^2 \sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + \sigma^2
$$

Putting it all together:
$$
E(\text{SSE}) = E(\text{SST}) - E(\text{SSR}) = \beta_1^2 \sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2 + n\sigma^2 - \beta_1^2 \sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2 - \sigma^2 = (n-1)\sigma^2
$$
Thus, I ended up with:
$$
E(\text{SSE}) = (n-1)\sigma^2
$$


Question: Why am I getting $E(\text{SSE}) = (n-1)\sigma^2$ instead of the expected $E(\text{SSE}) = (n-2)\sigma^2$? Where am I going wrong in my derivation? I suspect it has something to do with the degrees of freedom, but I'm not sure how that fits into my calculation.
Any help to resolve this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated!

just looked over, did not do calcs, here is a little thing: $\overline{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \overline{x} + \overline{\varepsilon}$

But isn't $\bar{\epsilon}$ = 0 as per the initial assumption of epsilon being Gaussian(0, sigma^2) ?

Sample average is different from population mean (which is zero).

The error is in step 2. The ESS is defined by ESS equals
$$\sum (y_i - \hat y_i)^2$$
The sum of squares of the prediction errors, not the sum of squares about the mean $\bar y$.
